# Is it is possible to mark code in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm currently still learning the basics of Java and I have dozens of exercises, many times I have trouble finishing them and I'm forced to either ask for help or copy the answers from Github. I want to be able to mark the code I didn't write myself so I can focus on what I have trouble with. I've only found something like that for Visual Studio Code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Bookmarks in Intelij](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Navigation_and_Search__Bookmarks.html) to "save" a place in your code and revisit them later.

Furthermore, you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>NUMBER</kbd> to toggle the bookmark for the given `NUMBER` and you can goto that bookmark with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>NUMBER</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use [bookmarks](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Navigation_and_Search__Bookmarks.html) or yur could use [comments](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-comments) to add some text of what you understand and what not.